# Elegant way to define the math environment as a command

Tags: macros, environments

I want to avoid typing "begin align" everytime and so I create such a new command

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\alignEnv}{\@ifstar{\@alignEnv}{\@@alignEnv}}
\newcommand{\@alignEnv}[1]{\begin{align*}
        #1
\end{align*}}
\newcommand{\@@alignEnv}[1]{\begin{align}
        #1
\end{align}}
\makeatother
```

This command is effective in most cases. However, when I type some math symbols like sum, texstudio will automatically complete `$` like

```
\alignEnv{$\sum_i$}
```

So I have to delete `$` manually, otherwise the system will report an error. I haven't find any command like `\ensuremath` to remove `$`. My questions are

1. Besides my method, could you provide any other elegant way to define a command for math environment? Any suggestions are appreciated!
2. Could you help me improve the `$` problem in my method?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd strongly advise against doing this. environments are the core syntactic feature of latex and hiding them adds no value. It just confuses any humans reading the source file as they will not recognise the construct and as you see it confuses editors that will find it harder to get correct syntax highlighting.  In most tex editors adding a known environment like `\begin{align}  \end{align}` will be available with a two or three keystroke combination, so defining a command will not save any typing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thank you for your valuable suggestion! I have found out how to set combination shortcuts in TeXstudio: Options > Configure TeXstudio > Shortcuts > Commands > Math ...

Comment: It should be noted that every environment is implemented using, for example, \align and \endalign.  OTOH, I'm not sure how much work is done by \begin and \end and how much is set up/hidden by \newenvironment.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for your comment! I grasp your meaning of "environment is implemented using \align...".  I tried `\align` first rather than `\alignEnv` in the morning and the editor told me that `\align` was used. I didn't understand why this bug occurred until now! Thank you~

Comment: wow! Only if we consider a problem from a higher perspective can we expand and deepen our understanding!